# httpd fails to start after ssl.conf was updated with virutal host

Tags: apache, ssl, centos

I'm able to get the website with ssl enabled for a single site.
If I add virtual hosts under ssl.conf, the httpd refuses to start and I did setenforce 0, still no luck.

More details:

I created different certificate for the new virtual host. But seems like issue persists.

Comment: This question is lacking details, i.e. it is clear what you've tried to do in general but not what you did exactly. Also please look into the error logs of your web server for more information, since failures to start typically leave helpful information there.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Here is what I did from the start.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Here is what I did from the start. 1. configured the httpd on my centOS server and started httpd service. httpd.conf was updated with virtual hosts. and the website was serving over http. Later, 2. I installed mod_ssl on my centos machine and i updated the certs and keys for one website and i was able to access website over https,

Comment: Now, 3. If i add virtual host under /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf, I am unable to start the httpd service. the virtual host config looks similar to below 
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.1:443>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP

        SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/star.example.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/ssl/star.example.com.key

Comment: These information neither provide __exactly__ what you were doing (just a bit more details) nor did you have a look at the __server error log__ which I strongly recommended. Note that any answers can only be as good as the information you provide - and right now your information are not that useful to narrow down the problem.

Comment: The error log shows the output as [Wed Aug 12 17:00:12.110723 2020] [ssl:emerg] [pid 1152] AH01910: Oops, no RSA, DSA or ECC server certificate found for 'v1.api.wesitename.com.

Comment: Steps followed:

1.Installed of httpd 
2.Updated the httpd.conf with virtual hosts and website is running when I borwse http://website:80
Below are the extra lines added to my httpd.conf & there were multiple sites and its working on port 80(http)
----------------------
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.website1.com
    ServerAlias website1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/website1.com/html
    ErrorLog /var/www/website1.com/log/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/website1.com/log/requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>
------------------------

Comment: 3. Installed mod_ssl
generated the certificate and key and placed under
SSLCertificateFile etc/pki/tls/certs/website1.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/website1.key
 And the DocumentRoot was pointed to index.php/indexhtml directory and I am able to access https://website1.com

Comment: 4. Here is the Problem: When I add new virtual host to ssl.conf, I am unable to start httpd, It fails.

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName website2.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/website2/public
       ErrorLog /var/www/error.website2.log
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/website2.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/website2.key
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

Comment: Please don't pollute the comments with unformatted stuff but include the information well-formatted in your question by editing it. Also, the error message is pretty clear: you don't have a certificate properly given for `v1.api.wesitename.com`. If I understand the rest of the information correct (hard to read because of the formatting) you only specified a certificate for a different site.